# throws java.lang.classCastException when cast subclass to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I get a wired ClassCastException when developing my app.
The full stack trace is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.MapSerializer cannot be cast to com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.ObjectSerializer
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.SerializeConfig.get(SerializeConfig.java:807) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.SerializeConfig.getObjectWriter(SerializeConfig.java:440) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.SerializeConfig.getObjectWriter(SerializeConfig.java:436) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer.getObjectWriter(JSONSerializer.java:416) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer.writeWithFieldName(JSONSerializer.java:331) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.ASMSerializer_10_RpcResult.write(Unknown Source) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer.write(JSONSerializer.java:285) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.toJSONString(JSON.java:760) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.toJSONString(JSON.java:698) 
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.toJSONString(JSON.java:663) 
    at com.pdd.service.ad.biz.common.base.filter.AdExceptionFilter.invoke(AdExceptionFilter.java:155) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.pinduoduo.arch.dubbo.filter.MultisetFilter.invoke(MultisetFilter.java:79) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.AccessControlFilter.invoke(AccessControlFilter.java:99) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.pinduoduo.arch.dove.client.service.DoveDubboAbstractFilterService.handle(DoveDubboAbstractFilterService.java:49) 
    at com.pinduoduo.arch.dove.client.filter.DoveDubboFilter.invoke(DoveDubboFilter.java:26) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.yiran.arch.cat.filter.CatRpcFilter.invoke(CatRpcFilter.java:185) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.pdd.service.ad.biz.common.base.filter.AdContextFilter.invoke(AdContextFilter.java:59) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ContextFilter.invoke(ContextFilter.java:72) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.pdd.iris.dubbo.filter.IrisDubboFilter.invoke(IrisDubboFilter.java:50) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.pdd.service.ad.biz.common.base.filter.AdGenericFilter.invoke(AdGenericFilter.java:85) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ClassLoaderFilter.invoke(ClassLoaderFilter.java:39) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.EchoFilter.invoke(EchoFilter.java:41) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:103) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.dubbo.DubboProtocol$1.reply(DubboProtocol.java:72) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.handleRequest(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:86) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.received(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:172) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.DecodeHandler.received(DecodeHandler.java:52) 
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.dispatcher.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:82) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The wired thing is that `MapSerializer` is a subclass which implements `ObjectSerializer`.
Check their signature:

```
package com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer;

public class MapSerializer extends SerializeFilterable implements ObjectSerializer{
   ....
}
```

Despite the situation,I wander in what circumstance will a cast from subclass to superclass throws `ClassCaseException`.

Comment: how did you instantiate the object? how are you trying to cast it?

Comment: The code throws this exception is not written by me. 
It seems like a implict cast generated by compiler when use generic type.

Comment: My crystal ball says multiple classloaders involved.